# Проблемы с само подписыванием номера соединения в сокете(не видно переменной)

Tags: php, websocket, redbeanphp, ratchet, realtime

Пытаюсь докопаться до решения проблемы, php сокет работает через консольное приложение, мне надо передать переменную  $STid в это консольное приложение, Проблема в том, что оно не видит даже cookie  хотя они существуют(консольная программа находится внутри корня сайта 
Файл из которого надо отправить(по прямой ссылке переменная есть)

```
<?
  require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.php";
  if(isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['hash'])){
    if(!empty($_COOKIE['id']) && !empty($_COOKIE['hash'])){
     $sddd = R::findOne( 'user', ' id = ? ', array($_COOKIE['id']));
     if($sddd->hash == $_COOKIE['hash']){
  $STid = $_COOKIE['id'];
     }else{
       //ошибка безопасности
     }
    }else{
      //ошибка безопасности
    }
  }else{
    //ошибка безопасности
  }
```

IoServer.php (101-102 строка)

```
<?php
namespace Ratchet\Server;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use React\EventLoop\LoopInterface;
use React\Socket\ServerInterface;
use React\EventLoop\Factory as LoopFactory;
use React\Socket\Server as Reactor;




/**
 * Creates an open-ended socket to listen on a port for incoming connections.
 * Events are delegated through this to attached applications
 */
class IoServer {
    /**
     * @var \React\EventLoop\LoopInterface
     */
    public $loop;

    /**
     * @var \Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface
     */
    public $app;

    /**
     * Array of React event handlers
     * @var \SplFixedArray
     */
    protected $handlers;

    /**
     * The socket server the Ratchet Application is run off of
     * @var \React\Socket\ServerInterface
     */
    public $socket;

    /**
     * @param \Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface  $app      The Ratchet application stack to host
     * @param \React\Socket\ServerInterface       $socket   The React socket server to run the Ratchet application off of
     * @param \React\EventLoop\LoopInterface|null $loop     The React looper to run the Ratchet application off of
     */
    public function __construct(MessageComponentInterface $app, ServerInterface $socket, LoopInterface $loop = null) {
        if (false === strpos(PHP_VERSION, "hiphop")) {
            gc_enable();
        }

        set_time_limit(0);
        ob_implicit_flush();

        $this->loop = $loop;
        $this->app  = $app;
        $this->socket = $socket;

        $socket->on('connection', array($this, 'handleConnect'));

        $this->handlers = new \SplFixedArray(3);
        $this->handlers[0] = array($this, 'handleData');
        $this->handlers[1] = array($this, 'handleEnd');
        $this->handlers[2] = array($this, 'handleError');

    }

    /**
     * @param  \Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface $component The application that I/O will call when events are received
     * @param  int                                $port      The port to server sockets on
     * @param  string                             $address   The address to receive sockets on (0.0.0.0 means receive connections from any)
     * @return IoServer
     */
    public static function factory(MessageComponentInterface $component, $port = 80, $address = '0.0.0.0') {
        $loop   = LoopFactory::create();
        $socket = new Reactor($loop);
        $socket->listen($port, $address);

        return new static($component, $socket, $loop);
    }

    /**
     * Run the application by entering the event loop
     * @throws \RuntimeException If a loop was not previously specified
     */
    public function run() {
        if (null === $this->loop) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("A React Loop was not provided during instantiation");
        }

        // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        $this->loop->run();
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }

    /**
     * Triggered when a new connection is received from React
     * @param \React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function handleConnect($conn) {
        $conn->decor = new IoConnection($conn);
//задаем номер соединения


require_once("D:/user/config/DbTroin.php");
        $conn->decor->resourceId    =  $STid;



//задаем номер соединения
        $conn->decor->remoteAddress = $conn->getRemoteAddress();

        $this->app->onOpen($conn->decor);

        $conn->on('data', $this->handlers[0]);
        $conn->on('end', $this->handlers[1]);
        $conn->on('error', $this->handlers[2]);
    }

    /**
     * Data has been received from React
     * @param string                            $data
     * @param \React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function handleData($data, $conn) {
        try {
            $this->app->onMessage($conn->decor, $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->handleError($e, $conn);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A connection has been closed by React
     * @param \React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function handleEnd($conn) {
        try {
            $this->app->onClose($conn->decor);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->handleError($e, $conn);
        }

        unset($conn->decor);
    }

    /**
     * An error has occurred, let the listening application know
     * @param \Exception                        $e
     * @param \React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function handleError(\Exception $e, $conn) {
        $this->app->onError($conn->decor, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы хотите консольное приложение, то о каких cookie вы вообще ведёте речь?

Comment: Это библиотека, запускается либо через скрипт на сайте(по прямой ссылке) или через консоль( это сокет) предназначенный для сайта